# error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dry-plains-3718.git'

Tags: django, heroku, github

Here what i am getting :

```
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 3.60 KiB, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:dry-plains-3718.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dry-plains-3718.git'
```

Earlier i thought it was problem of .gitignore file but that also working fine . I have ingnored my virutal env  and *.pyc as given in documentation.
I tried :

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

also I had to add my pub key to heroku.

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

this is also not able solve my problem. 
I don't know much about the heroku implementation. Anything specific I should check or try?

Please help me as i referred many documents but still getting same error . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe cedar recognizes django apps by the existance of a requirements.txt file.

Pleaee check is to be sure you have created 'requirements.txt' and 'Procfile' in the root of your source tree that is being pushed. The names are case sensitive.

This tutorial includes instructions on creating them:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django